# Use service with Pinia

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, pinia

I have a service, which handles the API communication (and should be the only file to do actual API calls). I have some issues to use this service in my store.

My current logic looks like this:
To swap the service out for better testability, the service is introduced to the Vue component via a prop. My issue is, that i could not find a good way to tell the store to use this service, so i created a composable `useService` to 'store' the service, which can then be imported and used in the store.

```js
// component.vue
const props = defineProps<{
  service: ServiceInterface
}>()

// Get the composable and set the service
const actualService = useService()
actualService.setService(props.service)

// Use the store
const store = useStore()
```

```js
// useService.ts
const service = ref<ServiceInterface>()

export const useService = () => {
  const setService = (newService: ServiceInterface) => {
    service.value = newService
  }

  return {
    service,
    setService
  }
}
```

```js
// useStore.ts

// import composable
const { service } = useService()

export const useStore = defineStore('storeName', {
  actions: {
    async fetchData(id: string) {
      // Ensure service is set
      if (!service.value) {
        throw new Error('No service')
      }

      // Use service
      service.value.getData(id)
    }
  }
})
```

This setup does work, however i need to double check in every method that the service is available and i feel like i overcomplicated the whole setup. Has somebody any idea to improve this flow?

I guess i am looking for something like this (not working):

```js
export const useStore = (service: ServiceInterface) => {
  return defineStore('storeName', {
    actions: {
      async fetchData(id: string) {
        service.getData(id)
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason why you should make the service reactive. You want to be able to replace it with a mock in testing, but you don't need the ability to replace any of its methods on the fly once it has been instantiated (which is the only reason you'd want it to be reactive)

I'd go with (`service.ts`):

```
export const someCall = (...args) => {
  // make some call here, using optional args
},
export const someOtherCall = (...args) => {
  // make some other call here, using optional args
}
```

Anywhere else:

```
import { someCall, someOtherCall } from '@/path/to/service'
// use them directly
```

Or:

```js
import * as service from '@/path/to/service'
// use service.someCall(args)
```

**Note:** replace `...args` above with the actual arguments needed for each call.

---

You can replace `service.ts` in your tests with ease:

```js
jest.mock('@/path/to/service')
```

Or mock a specific method only:

```js
const mockSomeOtherCall = jest.fn()
jest.mock('@/path/to/service', () => {
  ...jest.requireActual('@/path/to/service'),
  someOtherCall: mockSomeOtherCall
})

it('calls someOtherCall', () => {
  mockSomeOtherCall.mockReset()

  // mount component here, then:

  expect(mockSomeOtherCall).not.toHaveBeenCalled()

  // trigger something that should call `someOtherCall` then:

  expect(mockSomeOtherCall)
    .toHaveBeeCalledWith(expectedArgumentValues);
})
```

---

**Note:** in the above code `@/path/to/service` is generic. If, for example, you place `service.ts` (or `.js`) inside `src/services`, the path would actually be `@/services/service`. In a test suite, by using `jest.mock('@/services/service')` (or any of its more specific variants), you're effectively replacing the actual contents of that module with mocks, while running the tests in that test suite.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Sorry to follow up, but how would you use that approach with Pinia? Maybe i am missing it, but with this way i am not able to uncouple service and store, right? Since i would have to import `/path/to/service` i am not able to swap out the service. I updated my question to hopefully clarify, what i am looking for.

Comment: In store you simply import the service from wherever it is and you use it. In tests, when you declare `jest.mock('@/path/to/service')` the store will automatically get the replacement from the import, instead of the actual thing. And when you want a specific response from a specific call, you specify it in the mock: `mockSomeOtherCall = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(/* response here */)`. In that test, when the store calls `someOtherCall` it will receive the response you provided in the mock and you can test the store does what it's supposed to with that response.

Comment: So all you need for your example to work is `import * as service from '@/path/to/service'` and `async fetchData(id: string) { return service.getData(id).then(response => { /* use response to modify state */ }) }`, provided you have a `getData` declared in `service`, of course.

Comment: You don't need to pass the `service` as an argument to the store. I don't know where you picked that up from, but it's not necessary. Simply `import` whatever you need from service at the top of the file and use them in the store's actions.